# Determine asymmetric latencies in a network

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, latency, cluster-computing

Imagine you have many clustered servers, across many hosts, in a heterogeneous network environment, such that the connections between servers may have wildly varying latencies and bandwidth.  You want to build a map of the connections between servers by transferring data between them.

Of course, this map may become stale over time as the network topology changes - but lets ignore those complexities for now and assume the network is relatively static.

Given the latencies between nodes in this host graph, calculating the bandwidth is a relative simply timing exercise.  I'm having more difficulty with the latencies - however.  To get round-trip time, it is a simple matter of timing a return-trip ping from the local host to a remote host - both timing events (start, stop) occur on the local host.

What if I want one-way times under the assumption that the latency is not equal in both directions?  Assuming that the clocks on the various hosts are not precisely synchronized (at least that their error is of the the same magnitude as the latencies involved) - how can I calculate the one-way latency?

In a related question - is this asymmetric latency (where a link is quicker in direction than the other) common in practice?  For what reasons/hardware configurations?  Certainly I'm aware of asymmetric bandwidth scenarios, especially on last-mile consumer links such as DSL and Cable, but I'm not so sure about latency.

**Added:** After considering the comment below, the second portion of the question is probably better off on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/96824/is-assymetric-latency-common-in-practice).

Comment: This is a great question for serverfault.

Comment: I struggled with whether to put here or serverfault, but I settled here since I believe it is a pure network programming question, rather than an administrative question per the SF raison-d'etre:

"Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity."

I concede, however, that the sub-question of what might incur such asymmetric latencies (rather than the theoretical question of how to calculate them) is probably better posed on SF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, asymmetric latencies -- especially "last mile" asymmetries -- cannot be automatically determined, because any network time synchronization protocol is equally affected by the same asymmetry, so you don't have a point of reference from which to evaluate the asymmetry.

If each endpoint had, for example, its own GPS clock, then you'd have a reference point to work from.

In *[Fast Measurement of LogP Parameters
for Message Passing Platforms](http://ipdps.cc.gatech.edu/2000/rtspp/18001181.pdf)*, the authors note that latency measurement requires clock synchronization external to the system being measured.  (Boldface emphasis mine, italics in original text.)

> Asymmetric latency can only be measured by sending a message with a timestamp *t<sub>s</sub>*, and letting the receiver derive the latency from *t<sub>r</sub> - t<sub>s</sub>*, where *t<sub>r</sub>* is the receive time. This **requires clock synchronization** between sender and receiver.  Without **external** clock synchronization (like using GPS receivers or specialized software like the *network time protocol*, NTP), clocks can only be synchronized up to a **granularity of the roundtrip time** between two hosts [10], which is useless for measuring network latency.

No network-based algorithm (such as NTP) will eliminate last-mile link issues, though, since every input to the algorithm will itself be uniformly subject to the performance characteristics of the last-mile link and is therefore not "external" in the sense given above.  (I'm confident it's possible to construct a proof, but I don't have time to construct one right now.)

Comment: I wondered about that.  Can you prove it, or provide a reference?

Comment: Reference and explanation given.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called One-Way Ping (OWAMP) specifically to solve this issue.  Activity can be seen in the LKML for adding high resolution timestamps to incoming packets (`SO_TIMESTAMP`, `SO_TIMESTAMPNS`, etc) to assist in the calculation of this statistic.

http://www.internet2.edu/performance/owamp/

There's even a Java version:

http://www.av.it.pt/jowamp/

Note that packet timestamping really needs hardware support and many present generation NICs only offer millisecond resolution which may be out-of-sync with the host clock.  There are MSDN articles in the DDK about synchronizing host & NIC clocks demonstrating potential problems.  Timestamps in nanoseconds from the TSC is problematic due to core differences and may require Nehalem architecture to properly work at required resolutions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552492(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [sping tool](https://github.com/benjojo/sping) is a new development in this space, which uses clock synchronization against nearby NTP servers, or an even more accurate source in the form of a GNSS box, to estimate asymmetric latencies.

The approach is covered in more detail [in this blog post](https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/post/ping-with-loss-latency-split).

Answer (score 0):

You can measure asymmetric latency on link by sending different sized packets to a port that returns a fixed size packet, like send some udp packets to a port that replies with an icmp error message. The icmp error message is always the same size, but you can adjust the size of the udp packet you're sending.

see http://www.cs.columbia.edu/techreports/cucs-009-99.pdf

Comment: You're assuming transfer time is solely a function of packet size - which isn't necessarily true

Comment: I don't have the time to read the entire paper, but from the abstract, it's about determining asymmetric bandwidths.  When it says "asymmetric links" it isn't talking about latency AFAI can see.  It isn't even talking exclusively about the asymmetry of the up/down-link of one pipe.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of a synchronized clock, the asymmetry cannot be measured as proven in the 2011 paper `"Fundamental limits on synchronizing clocks over networks".`

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224183858_Fundamental_Limits_on_Synchronizing_Clocks_Over_Networks