# Javascript clock synchronized with atomic clock

Tags: javascript, clock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The best way to synchronize client-side javascript clock with server date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date)

I want to make javascript clock that is synchronized with external server - with atomic clock server.
How to do that?

Comment: Have the javascript provide a hearbeat that keeps the server pushing data to the page. This is non trivial.

Comment: How to do that? Too broad a question. Show what you've tried. Questions without code are usually poor questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to synchronize client-side javascript clock with server date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date) or [Synchronizing Javascript clock with server clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272978/synchronizing-javascript-clock-with-server-clock)

Comment: Too broad question. Whatever of the many different client-server communcation methods you use, in JavaScript you're always limited by [network latency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1942877/1048572). See also [Sync JS time between multiple devices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10585910/1048572).